# Xcode SDK 4.0.2

Tags: iphone, sdk

Is there any way for me to download the iOS 4.0.1 SDK without actually downloading Xcode AGAIN as well? I just think since I already have the most recent version it would be good to save time and space by simply downloading the SDK.

However - I do realize they might have updated Xcode so that it is compatible with new technologies. Does this mean I have to reinstall it?

Thanks,

Christian Stewart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to download and install the entire SDK, including Xcode and all the other tools, whenever Apple updates it.  There is no patch or incremental-update available.

Some developers take the additional step of uninstalling the previous SDK before installing the new one, to avoid having any "stale" files left in the installation directories.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks Kristopher. This was actually faster than the official iPhone forums for developers. 

Do you just recommend deleting the Developer folder?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: There is instruction in the SDK readme about how to uninstall.